# Updating values based on a group of records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I'm trying to carry out an update on the "*Keys*" column, where Janitor value is set to "*No_Name*". It should be updated to "*None*" only when all Janitors have a NULL value per Building Name. When a Janitor(s) do have a Key then set 'No_Name' as NULL still.

| Building Name | Janitor | Keys | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Building A | Andrew | Yes |  |
| Building A | Mike | Yes |  |
| Building A | Bill | NULL |  |
| Building A | Phil | Yes |  |
| Building A | No_Name | NULL | --- should stay NULL |
| Building B | Andrew | NULL |  |
| Building B | Mike | NULL |  |
| Building B | Bill | NULL |  |
| Building B | Phil | NULL |  |
| Building B | No_Name | NULL | --- should change to 'NONE' bcs no Owners have the keys |

Tried a bunch of AND/OR statements with no success.

Comment: SSMS is an IDE-like GUI application, so isn't relevent here. You talk about "cells" which implies you're using a spreadsheet application such as Excel (database tables don't have "cells", they have columns and rows, and a column in a row has a value). Are you therefore trying to use ACE and SQL against an xlsx file or something?

Comment: Thom - I am working in Microsoft SQL Server, not an excel spreadsheet. By CELL I am referring to VALUE, sorry for incorrect verbiage.

Comment: Love to see what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know the exact DBMS you're using, but the idea is generally the same.
You can use aggregation function like MAX() on Keys to generate list of buildings to update to None.

```
select "Building name"
from No_Name
group by "Building name"
having max(keys) <> NULL
```

this query will give you all building that have all NULL values in keys, then you can incorporate it in Update statement.

Comment: This helped, not sure why but it the Max function made me thinking of applying it to a count and then I solved by counting keys per building and updating based on those values. So thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could use an updatable table expression making use of a window aggregate:

```
update t 
  set Keys = case when k is null then 'None' end
from (
  select *, Max(keys) over(partition by Building_Name) k
  from t
)t
where Janitor = 'No_Name';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try going with an `EXISTS` expression.

```
UPDATE tab
SET Keys = 'None'
WHERE Janitor = 'No_Name'
  AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                 FROM tab t2 
                 WHERE tab.BuildingName = t2.BuildingName AND t2.Keys IS NOT NULL);
```

**Output**:

| BuildingName | Janitor | Keys |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Building A | Andrew | Yes |
| Building A | Mike | Yes |
| Building A | Bill | null |
| Building A | Phil | Yes |
| Building A | No_Name | null |
| Building B | Andrew | null |
| Building B | Mike | null |
| Building B | Bill | null |
| Building B | Phil | null |
| Building B | No_Name | None |

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/3xvGJppS).